# ListView one item per screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Since [DirectionalViewPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) is deprecated now, I need some way to mimic its' vertical paging functionlity.

First thing that comes to my mind is ListView, but I'd like some tips for implementing row per screen funcitonality - where do I start ?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you be able to use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), perhaps with an animation using a [PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html)?

Comment: I'm sorry to not mention that 2.3+ version should be supported. PageTransformer has no effect on 2.3

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? If so can you please share with us?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Top extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    String[] rows = {1,2,3,4}; //This rows array Determine the no of rows to be displayed on the list
    setContentView(R.layout.top);//layout for activity
    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.top_list, R.id.topName, rows);  
}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) 
    {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);          
    }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {               
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_list, parent, false); //top_list is the seperate layout that represents your list consider it has one TextView.
            String[] rows = {1,2,3,4};          
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);   
            tv.setText(rows[position]);

            return row;
        }           
    }
}
```

1. Extend ListActivity Instead of Activity.
2. Create two layout one for the Activity and the other for the list.
3. The rows array determine the no of lists in the listview.
4. The position determines the list number.

I hope this helps ask if any other clarification needed.

Comment: Are you sure it will display one row per screen ? From you code I can't think of anything that helps achieving it.

Comment: what exactly you mean by "implementing row per screen funcitonality";

Comment: I mean Vertical ViewPager.